# The servlet is not redirecting the page after logging in to the site, In network, the dashboard file has a status code of over 200 but no redirection

Tags: java, servlets

I have a web application with a login system, when logging into the website, there is no redirection of the page to the dashboard, 
When checking the chrome browser terminal, the dashboard file has status code 200, but without page redirection.

```java
package DAO;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            switch(request.getServletPath()){
                case "/Login" :  {
                    String email = request.getParameter("email").trim();
                    String senha = request.getParameter("senha").trim();
                    UsuarioDAO usudao = new UsuarioDAO();
                    if(usudao.login(email, senha)){
                        response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
                        response.setHeader("location", "http://localhost:8080/dbdfacu2/dashboard.jsp");
                    }
                }
                break;
                case "/Register" : {
                    String nome = request.getParameter("nome").trim();
                    String email = request.getParameter("email").trim();
                    String senha = request.getParameter("senha").trim();
                    UsuarioDAO usudao = new UsuarioDAO();
                    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                        out.println(usudao.inserir(nome, email, senha));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception erro) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ERRO Ajax" + erro);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI1I6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [resp.sendRedirect](https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-redirect-forward) instead

> ```
> resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/redirected");
> ```
>
> We use original response object to redirect this request to another URL